# Brace For Something

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage, reflexive-pronouns

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*brace*".  According to definition 1 of this [dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brace_1), a person could "*brace oneself*" (and only the same self) for some adverse situation.  But then, there is this usage in some news [article](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2016/03/05/gop-dem-candidates-gear-up-for-weekend-primaries-caucuses.html):

> Clinton’s ***campaign manager braced supporters*** for the potential setback in a memo Wednesday that suggested the former secretary of state may lose the caucus states this weekend.

which suggests that a person could "*brace*" another person for some adverse situation.  Is the usage in the article wrong, or is the dictionary missing an entry?

Comment: As is customary in many of your questions, you have presumed something that isn't explicitly stated. In particular, the dictionary does **not** say "and only the same self" – that's a restriction you have erroneously added. The usage is not wrong, nor is the dictionary missing an entry; the entry says quite simply, "get ready for something unpleasant," so the sentence means, "Clinton’s campaign manager got supporters ready for something unpleasant."

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford Dictionary includes this among its definitions of **brace**:

> "Prepare (someone or oneself) for something difficult or unpleasant."

See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/brace

I believe this definition was simply overlooked by the Macmillan Dictionary.